# Grail (web browser) installation on Scientific Linux

Tags: python, browser

I'm not sure if Grail browser is a good choice nowadays, however I want to try it, because I have some problems about graphics running on Firefox-Fermi. The next, is what I obtain after trying grail-0.6 (tgz)

```
# python grail.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "grail.py", line 43, in ?
from Tkinter import *
```

After installing "tkinter" adequately, I run "grail.py" again, and I get

```
# python grail.py 
/root/grail-0.6/grailbase/app.py:6: Deprecation Warning: the regex module is   
deprecated; please use the re module
import regex
/usr/lib/python2.4/regsub.py:15: DeprecationWarning: the regsub module is  
deprecated; please use re.sub()
DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "grail.py", line 499, in ?
main()
File "grail.py", line 108, in main
app = Application(prefs=prefs, display=display)
File "grail.py", line 248, in __init__
self.stylesheet = Stylesheet.Stylesheet(self.prefs)
File "/root/grail-0.6/Stylesheet.py", line 21, in __init__
self.load()
File "/root/grail-0.6/Stylesheet.py", line 45, in load
massaged.append((g, c), v % fparms_dict)
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

but now, I'm not able to understand the message at all. May you advice me about this problem?

Comment: How exactly do you run `grail.py`? `python setup.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - that's a blast from the past!  My advice is to give up:  Grail hasn't been touched in more than a dozen years.  It's dead.

The error message you're getting stems from a change made way back in Python 1.6 (released 5 September 2000).  Here's the message from the release notes:

> - The append() method for lists can no longer be invoked with more
>     than one argument.  This used to append a single tuple made out of
>     all arguments, but was undocumented.  To append a tuple, use
>     e.g. l.append((a, b, c)).

So, you can:

1. Give up.  Recommended ;-)
2. Install an ancient version of Python; or,
3. Change that line to

   `massaged.append(((g, c), v % fparms_dict))`

and see what breaks next ;-)

### About the next problem

Python 0.9.1 is *extremely* old, from early 1991.  The language changed in many, many ways before 1.0 was released.

According to [the old Grail home page](http://grail.sourceforge.net/), Grail 0.6:

> requires Python 1.5 or newer, and Tcl/Tk 8.0 or newer.

So find Python 1.5 if you're determined to pursue this ;-)  Note that the `.append()` semantics were changed in version 1.6, so the original `.append()` code that hurt you at first should still work OK in 1.5.