# Installing Grail-0.6 (web browser) on Scientific Linux

Tags: python, browser

Almost like in question [19802270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802270/grail-web-browser-installation-on-scientific-linux), I tried to install Grail-0.6 with python-0.91 and it happened that:

```
#./python /root/grail-0.6/grail.py
Parsing error: file /root/grail-0.6/grail.py, line 8: if __name__ ==  
 '_main__':
^
Unhandled exception: run-time error: syntax error.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem in your first post was solved, please go back and [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

For this one, Python 0.9.1 is extremely old, from early 1991. The language changed in many, many ways before 1.0 was released.

According to the [old Grail home page](http://grail.sourceforge.net/), Grail 0.6:

> requires Python 1.5 or newer, and Tcl/Tk 8.0 or newer.

So find Python 1.5 if you're determined to pursue this ;-) Note that the `.append()` semantics were changed in version 1.6, so the original `.append()` code that hurt you at first should still work OK in 1.5.

Way back in 0.9.1, Python had no `==` operator.  `=` was used for both equality testing and assignment.  That's why you got a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: It did not work too... File "./Lib/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 8, in ? --> import _tkinter #If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk, ImportError: No module named _tkinter...

Comment: @paritto, sorry, can't help with that - I don't know much about `Tcl/Tk`.  Maybe you need to find and install `Tcl/Tk 8.0` too :-(